# Unable to secure pdf uploaded files or how do you preventing direct linking to website files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

I have a problem in sitefinity with .Net and while running the project after link of the pdf file.

what is the problem means i have logged in my system and open pdf i can view the pdf file opening in a new tab.( Here we are checking the current user session is active means opening the pdf). Suppose if logged in my system and copy the url and opening in the another system. Its should check the current user session exist or not if active means opening the pdf or else restrict like Access Denied.

I have an idea of like taking the url of the pdf file and while clicking on the pdf file opening in a new tab, while opening in i'm going to check the still current user is still active in current system if other system it'll not to open.

Please give me any idea to restrict to download.Shall I write the handler to handle for custom control.

I'm follow up the url.

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/unable-to-secure-pdfs-uploaded-in-documents-files

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/security/how-do-you-preventing-direct-linking-to-website-files

Please give me some idea,I'll be appreciate.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the Permissions settings for that file in Sitefinity (or its parent library/folder). 
You can remove Everyone group and instead add Authenticated Users group or any other role you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Some website administration tools allow for protecting resources based on the referer sent by the browser. It may have a label like "hotlink protection". In the end, IIS is configured such that some URLs will be accepted only when a referer showing your site is present.

Also take a look at Hanselman's blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BlockingImageHotlinkingLeechingAndEvilSploggersWithIISUrlRewrite.aspx